# opening file odd error in python 3

Tags: python

i have a quick question so im trying to code up something in python to open up a file and im getting a weird error when i run it ill post the error below with my code included, but ive never seen it before and im not sure what it means. if anyone has any ideas id really appreciate it. thanks !

**code**

```
def readfile():
    filename = input(str("What is the files name you would like to import "))
    f = open(filename)
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

**error**

> builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in
>   position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You don't need the `str` here. `"What is the files name you would like to import "` is already a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an encoding mismatch - you are trying to read the file in ASCII (which Python has detected from your operating system settings), when it is encoded in something else. You can specify an encoding when you open it:

```
f = open(filename, encoding='utf-8')
```

UTF-8 might not be the right encoding here either, but if you expect the file to contain mostly English words, it is probably a good guess. Ideally, you should try to find out the encoding of the file another way if you can - checking the settings of any program that successfully opens it can help, or if you're on a Unix-like system, the `file` command might tell you.

Comment: and since he doesn't close the file it's better to use: with open(filename) as f

Comment: so my code is right? its just the way the file is encoded then?